# How do I fix my Canon Rebel taking 2 pictures at once after a 10 second delay?

Tags: canon

What can I do about this?  I don't know the adjustment to make it only take one picture at a time immediately.

Comment: It sounds almost like you have mirror lockup enabled (do Rebels even allow mirror lockup?), along with the self timer. It *sounds* like an image is being taken when the mirror locks up, then ten seconds later the image is taken.

Comment: My 550D certainly allows mirror lockup (Custom Function 8, if anyone really cares!)

Answer (score 4):

The only thing I can think of that would cause this (other than a broken camera) is if you have it shooting a bracket after a timer delay.  Normally Canon cameras have options of 2 second or 10 second delays and the indicator often looks like a little exclamation point with a wire(actually supposed to be a remote shutter.)  Does a light on the front blink during the 10 seconds?  If so, this indicates the timer is operating.  You will want to change the drive mode away from timer.

More specific instructions on turning off bracketing and changing the drive mode will depend on the specific model of Rebel that you have.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds very much like you're in one of the self-timer modes. You should be able to change this via the Quick Menu, or via one of the direction controls; on the 550D, it's the "left" button or the bottom-right hand option on the Quick Menu - [this picture](http://www.dpreview.com/reviews/CanonEOS550D/images/allroundview2.jpg) should give you a clue as to what you need to look for on your camera. Alternatively, look for the words "self-timer" in your manual.